# What does wolfram alpha means by this

Tags: limits, wolfram-alpha

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!(-e)^n}{n^n} = \exp (i~0~to~2\pi)\infty$$

Does [it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20n%20to%20infinity%20n!%2Fn%5En%20(-e)%5En) have a specific meaningful answer or is it just infinity? is it related to complex series? where can I read more about it?

Comment: this means that the Limit is infinity

Comment: @DR.SonnhardGraubner Thank you!

Comment: ok nice that i could help you

Comment: $n! (-e)^n \approx n^n \sqrt{2 \pi n}$ so you have $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{2 \pi n} $ but wolfram alpha interpreted it as $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{2 \pi n}(-1)^n $ and its the right way to do it since $(-e)^n$ is a mere approximation in the Stirling approximation of $n!$, now $|\sqrt{2 \pi n}(-1)^n|$ goes to $+\infty$ when $n \to \infty$, so $(-1)^n$ does not effect the magnitude which is $+\infty$ but effect the angel(this is just to say why the odd result by Wolfram) in a short answer , it does goes to $\infty$ or at least you could say the limit have no finite answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this starts with the two limits

$$ \lim_{\substack{n \to \infty \\ n \text{ even}}} \frac{n!(-e)^n}{n^n} = +\infty \text{ and } \lim_{\substack{n \to \infty \\ n \text{ odd}}} \frac{n!(-e)^n}{n^n} = -\infty. $$

Notice that the $(-1)^n$ in the numerator causes it to flip between positive and negative.

Now what I believe WolframAlpha is doing is treating $n$ as a real number. If this happens then

$$ (-1)^n = (e^{\pi i})^n = e^{n \pi i}. $$

Now, if you look at the sequence $n = a, a + 2\pi, a + 4\pi, \dots, a+ 2k\pi,\dots$ this value is always equal to

$$ e^{a \pi i}. $$

The rest of the limit, $n!e^n/n^n$ goes to infinity, so what you are left with is

$$ e^{a \pi i} \infty $$

where $a$ can take on any real number. But because adding or subtracting $2\pi$ from $a$ doesn't change the value of the exponential, we can restrict our attention to $a$ in the interval $[0,2\pi)$. This gives the answer

$$ e^{[0,2\pi)i} \infty $$

which is supposed to represent a value of $\infty$ but at every possible angle in the complex plane.